# Input box to search for sheet

Tags: vba, excel

i was wondering if there is any VBA code which allows an input box to search for a sheet with the use of a drop down list and to redirect to sheet automatically after the user has searched. Similar to how we find data on excel except for that fact that it is sheets now. The  drop down list should contain all the sheets in the workbook so that they can select the sheet they want to go to.  i have a code which works whereby user has to type manually which can be troublesome if the sheet names are too long thus resulting to spelling or format errors.

```
Sub searchsheet()


Dim strsheet As String
' dim i as integer

strsheet = Application.InputBox("put sheet name", "Sheet Name Select", , , , , , 2)


With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strsheet)
.Select
.Activate
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You would need something that keeps your list up-to-date as sheets are added/removed.

Comment: Something like a summary sheet?Is it like defining a range from the summary sheet for the dropdown list. How do i code it here? @Bond

Comment: You'd probably want to iterate the sheets each time before displaying your dialog/dropdown to make sure your list is current.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will show a combo box on a user form, but the combo can be placed on a sheet as well

UserForm:

### [image: user form with combo box]

- Create a new UserForm with default name "UserForm1" (any size)
- Create a new ComboBox with default name "ComboBox1" (any size)
- Add this code to the form VBA module:

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If Len(ComboBox1) > 0 Then Worksheets(ComboBox1.Text).Activate
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    If KeyAscii = vbKeyEscape Then Me.Hide
End Sub
```

---

- Create a new standard VBA module and add this code:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub navigateSheets()
    Dim cmb As ComboBox, ws As Worksheet

    Set cmb = UserForm1.ComboBox1
    cmb.Clear
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Visible Then cmb.AddItem ws.Name
    Next
    cmb.ListIndex = 0
    setUserForm
End Sub

Private Sub setUserForm()
    With UserForm1
        .Height = 50:   .Width = 111
        .Caption = "Navigate Sheets"
        With .ComboBox1
            .BackColor = RGB(240, 250, 255)
            .ControlTipText = "Select Sheet"
            .Height = 17:   .Width = UserForm1.Width - 15
            .Top = 7:       .Left = 7:  .ListRows = 22
            .MatchEntry = fmMatchEntryFirstLetter   '0
        End With
        .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

---

- Run **`navigateSheets()`** to move between visible sheets, and pres Esc to close the form

Comment: Nothing seems to come out from the droplist @paul bica

Comment: Did you execute navigateSheets() step by step? (by pressing F8). You also need to have a UserForm called "UserForm1" and on it a ComboBox called "ComboBox1", and the code in the UserForm module

Comment: oh sorry it runs! I ran it on the wrong module. @paul bica